# How do I add image captions using a custom style?

Tags: media

I am not a programmer.

However, I need to know how to use css to add a caption for an image field in a node.

Comment: how are you generating your image html/css in the first place?

Comment: image field in a node

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way would be to create your own theme_image() in your theme's template.php file.  It would be pretty straightforward, just grab drupal's default theme_image() from theme.inc and add a span to it:

If Drupal 6:

```
function YOURTHEMENAME_image($path, $alt = '', $title = '', $attributes = NULL, $getsize = TRUE) {
  if (!$getsize || (is_file($path) && (list($width, $height, $type, $image_attributes) = @getimagesize($path)))) {
    $attributes = drupal_attributes($attributes);
    $url = (url($path) == $path) ? $path : (base_path() . $path);
    return '<img src="'. check_url($url) .'" alt="'. check_plain($alt) .'" title="'. check_plain($title) .'" '. (isset($image_attributes) ? $image_attributes : '') . $attributes .' /><span class="caption">' . check_plain($title) . '</span>';
  }
}
```

If Drupal 7:

```
function YOURTHEMENAME_image($variables) {
  $attributes = $variables['attributes'];
  $attributes['src'] = file_create_url($variables['path']);

  foreach (array('width', 'height', 'alt', 'title') as $key) {

    if (isset($variables[$key])) {
      $attributes[$key] = $variables[$key];
    }
  }

  return '<img' . drupal_attributes($attributes) . ' /><span class="caption">' . (isset($variables['title']) ? $variables['title'] : '') . '</span>';
}
```

Clear caches/theme registry and now every image will have a span with class `caption` after it with the image's title in it (or blank if none obviously).  If you want to get fancier with wrappers and so forth, just put whatever html you want/need in the return's above.

Then CSS this however you want.